# sequelize.js association accessor

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I made API server with Node.js

Also I use sequelize.js(version 4) for communicate with MySQL.

My table structure is here.

> [Article]
>
> - no(PK)
> - subject
> - content
> - created_at
> - updated_at
>
> [Comment]
>
> - no(PK)
> - content
> - created_at
> - updated_at
> - article_no(FK to Article)

[index.controller.js]

```
import { Article, Comment } from '../model/model';

export const index = (req, res) => {
    res.send('controller index');
};


export const getArticle = (req, res) => {
    try {
        Article.all()
        .then(article => {
            res.status(200).json({status: true, result: article});
        });
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(500).json({status: false, result: "get article fail"});
    }
}
export const addArticle = (req, res) => {
    const { subject, content } = req.body;
    try {
        Article.create({
            subject: subject,
            content: content
        })
        res.status(200).json({status: true, result: "article write success"});
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(500).json({status: false, result: "article fail"});
    }
}
export const getComment = (req, res) => {
    try {
        Comment.all()
        .then(comment => {
            res.status(200).json({status: true, result: comment})
        });
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(500).json({status: false, result: "get comment fail"});
    }
}
export const addComment = (req, res) => {
    const { content, article_no } = req.body;
    try {
        Comment.create({
            content: content,
            article_no: article_no
        })
        .then(() => res.status(200).json({status: true, result: "comment write success"}))
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).json({status: false, result: "comment fail"});
    }
}
```

[index.js]

```
import express from 'express';
import { index, getArticle, getComment,addArticle, addComment } from './index.controller';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', index);

router.get('/article', getArticle);
router.post('/article', addArticle);
router.get('/comment', getComment);
router.post('/comment', addComment);

export default router;
```

[model.js]

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'id', 'pw', {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

export const Article = sequelize.define('article', {
    no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    subject: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true
})

export const Comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
    no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true
})

Article.hasMany(Comment, {as: 'Comments'}); // association
Comment.belongsTo(Article); // association

sequelize.sync({
    force: false
});
```

Because of association(`hasMany`, `belongsTo`), `article_no` column will be added to Comment table.

Refer to this document, http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#one-to-many-associations-hasmany-

It says that `Instances of Project will get the accessors getWorkers and setWorkers.`

In my case, it will be `getComments` and `setComments`.

But I don't know exactly how can I get all the comments related articles with using accessor.

Current output is here. (If I connect to `GET /article`)

```
{  
   "status":true,
   "result":[  
      {  
         "no":1,
         "content":"comment test",
         "created_at":"2018-07-18T05:00:45.000Z",
         "updated_at":"2018-07-18T05:00:45.000Z",
         "article_no":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Desired output is here

```
{  
   "status":true,
   "result":[  
      {  
         "no":1,
         "content":"comment test",
         "created_at":"2018-07-18T05:00:45.000Z",
         "updated_at":"2018-07-18T05:00:45.000Z",
         "article_no":1,
         "comments": [
            // related comments here!
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to join another model you should use include in your query

```
User.findAll({
  include: [
     { model: Profile, required: true // inner join }
  ],
  limit: 3
});
```

Check out the [Sequelize model usage](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html) docs.

To access the comments with accessors you will need do something like this:

```
const articles = await Article.all();

articles.forEach(article => {
  const comments = await article.getComments();
})
```

The idea behind is that each `article` sequelize object will have the accessor `getComments` but internally what it does when you execute `getComments` it makes a new request to the database with the prepopulated `articleId` in the comments where query. This is called lazy loading because you can load the data when you need it. But that is not your case.

For the desired output  I suggest to use the `include` method cause it will make a single request to the database.

Comment: Thanks. But document said, there is some method(accessor) likes get all items, set items. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Hide Developed the answer a bit.

Comment: I understand exactly. Thanks :)